# What is a REST API round trip?

Tags: node.js, rest

Every time i hear a talk regarding **REST API**, i come across the term "Round-trip", Can someone please point out what exactly this term represents?

Comment: not sure, but it should be time gap b/w request and response.

Comment: It's like the whole process of a tomato - from seed to the plate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round-trip means a request that the client performs to the server and the response that the server sends back to the client for that request.

Comment: But that sounds just like a simple request-response!